# CSS loading as empty file in Custom Theme

Tags: php, theme-development, css

Hello I made a custom theme and moved it from MAMP to a cloud server. For some reason the CSS is an empty file. File path is correct, checked the file in cPanel and it has the full .css sheet. But when I go to console and follow the path it is just empty. My .js file loads fine and I beleive i enqueued the paths properly.

Any help is greatly appreciated and thank you for your time!

Functions

```
<?php

function paramo_script_enqueue() {

    wp_enqueue_style('customstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/paramo.css'), array (), '1.0.0', all );
    wp_enqueue_script('customjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/paramo.js', array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-core'), '1.0.0', true );

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'paramo_script_enqueue');
function paramo_theme_setup() {

    add_theme_support('menus');

    register_nav_menu('primary', 'Primary Header Navigation');
    register_nav_menu('secondary', 'Footer Navigation');


}

add_action('init', 'paramo_theme_setup');

add_theme_support('custom-header');


//enqueues our locally supplied font awesome stylesheet
function enqueue_our_required_stylesheets(){
    wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.css'); 
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','enqueue_our_required_stylesheets');


?>
```

[image: css console path]

[image: js console path]

[image: cPanel Path]

Comment: the file "ParamoGaleria/css/paramo.css" is not empty. It returns a 404 error then it is certainly not uploaded on the server.

Comment: It is uploaded though. I updated the last photo of the cPanel.

Comment: are you also loading style.css somewhere else?

Comment: Can you solved your problem???

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue of "File Permission" to me. Please check the file permissions on the involved folders and files.

You should find an option to change permission on the top bar or by right-clicking in cpanel. On the other hand, you can also right-click on a folder or a file and change its permission via Filezilla.

The ideal value is 755 or 750 for directories and 644 or 640 for files.
Read more here the [codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions#Shared_Hosting_with_suexec)

Hope this helps.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Your `paramo_script_enqueue()` function has a simple syntax error. The `wp_enqueue_style()` function call has an add closing parenthesis before and a missing opening parenthesis around the dependencies parameter

issue in `'/css/paramo.css')` and `all` without parenthesis

replace

```
wp_enqueue_style('customstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/paramo.css'), array (), '1.0.0', all );
```

to

```
wp_enqueue_style('customstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/paramo.css', array (), '1.0.0', 'all' );
```

Visit Wordpress Doc  - [wp_enqueue_style()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/)

```
function paramo_script_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_style('customstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/paramo.css', array (), '1.0.0', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_script('customjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/paramo.js', array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-core'), '1.0.0', true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'paramo_script_enqueue');
```

Comment: Hello @Tony Garand  please try above code it is working for me after correction closing parenthesis and a missing opening parenthesis.